# download intra day data

Tags: finance, yahoo, intraday, google

I am trying to download intra day stock data for some 7000 symbols using google url :

> https://www.google.com/finance/getprices?q=RELIANCE&x=NSE&i=60&p=5d&f=d,c,o,h,l&df=cpct&auto=1&ts=1266701290218

so i am scheduling the program to be run every day, the problem i am facing is that after some url hits google block the request and redirect to bot verification page, same thing is with yahoo. Is there any other source for intrday data which doesn't block the request?

Answer (score 0):

You can try KineTick, free EndOfDay data http://www.kinetick.com/end-of-day

Comment: They want intraday data, not end-of-day.